# thymeleaf internationalization use default text html

Tags: spring, internationalization, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf with Spring Boot,

```
<span th:text="#{home.welcome}">Welcome Default Message</span>
```

When key is  not found in messages.properties, I had

```
??home.welcome_en_US??
```

I dont want to translate every message in  messages.properties. I would like to have "Welcome Default Message" writed in html page when translate key message is not found.

How I can do that?

Comment: Then add that to your `messages.properties` the values in that file are basically the defaults. The `message_yourLanguage.properties` contains the translated stuff.

Comment: In fact, I don't want to create default messages.properties, I want to use default message in thymeleaf html template.

Comment: You cannot as those are always replaced, that is how thyme leaf works. Maybe there is a solution in a custom dialect in which you can specify defaults in an expression.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not relevant anymore, but the following worked for me. I am running Thymeleaf 3.0.7.RELEASE.

```
<span th:text="${#strings.defaultString(#messages.msgOrNull('home.welcome'),'Welcome Default Message')}"/>
```

If message is not found, null is passed to the #strings.defaultString call which when given null parameter will return 'Welcome Default Message'.

More here http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings

Answer (score 2):

> Conditional display of element only in case if translation exists
>
> ```
> <p th:if="${#messages.msgOrNull('not.so.important.message')}" th:text="#{not.so.important.message}"></p>
> ```
>
> http://lukasgrygar.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-tips-and-tricks/

Which in your case could be used as:

```
<span>
 <th:block th:if="${#messages.msgOrNull('not.so.important.message')}" th:text="#{not.so.important.message}" />
 <th:block th:unless="${#messages.msgOrNull('not.so.important.message')}">Welcome Default Message</th:block>
</span>
```

Which is not the most elegant solution in your case if you want to display that default text.

Take a look at #messages utility methods at thymeleaf [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-b-expression-utility-objects).

And maybe you'll find more elegant solution. But still, my example solves your problem.

Comment: It's a first clue, may be I have to create my own th:properties to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Elvis operator in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-elvis):

```xml
<span th:text="${#messages.msgOrNull('home.welcome')?:'Welcome Default Message'}"></span>
```